# add text only version to an email template

Tags: mime, mandrill

We use mandrill to send emails and we have many templates defined to send emails. Below is one such template

```
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>

    <style type="text/css">
        ----- some styling information ----

    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    ------ Other html content ------
  </body>
</html>
```

As you can see there is no mention of text only version of this email template. To improve the chances of this email not going to spam i also want to add text only version of it as well. I got to know about "multipurpose internet mail extensions" but i still do not understand how i can make my email to have a text only version too.

I will be really grateful for any kind of help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strongly suggest using a templating service on top of Mandrill, such as apostle or sendwithus.

Makes it way easier to manage and edit html+text templates, and I believe both support your use case.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't indicate anything about your environment, where you're storing the templates, or whether you're using Mandrill's SMTP integration or API. Those things can make a difference in how/where you store the text versions of your templates.

- If you're generating the full SMTP message in some fashion in your system, then you'd need to create a multi-part/alternative MIME document to store the text version. Or use a library or templating engine that can generate this for you in accordance with the relevant specifications.
- If you're storing them in your system, and using the Mandrill API, then you'd want to store a separate text version to pass in the text parameter.
- For Mandrill templates, there's an explicit text version that can be provided and saved.

Alternately, Mandrill has an option to auto-convert your HTML to text. It can be configured in your [Sending Defaults](https://mandrillapp.com/settings/sending-options), or on a per-message basis through the API or with [SMTP headers](http://help.mandrill.com/entries/21688056-Using-SMTP-Headers-to-customize-your-messages#automatically-generate-plain-text-from-html-content).